# Access VBA getelementsbytagname windows 10 issue?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11, ms-access-2013

I have Access VBA scripts to pull data from a number of web sites.  These worked perfectly with office 2013 and Windows 7.  However, since upgrading to Windows 10 I have been getting intermittent errors (not necessarily in the same place with the same data) or sometimes data is not being extracted from the tags. It appears too occur when I access a specific tag with a specific index e.g.

```
tempV = TDelement.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
```

I'm using IE as the browser object created as follows:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Is there anything that upgrading Windows could have broken? (Novice, so apologies for any incorrect terminology)

Comment: Please use the backticks to properly format code expression. For example : `return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl))`. It makes your code more readable and improves your chance of getting an answer

Comment: No HTML or URL to make this [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the MSXML's [IXMLHTTPRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for web server requests. IE is no longer a dedicated browser on Windows, so may not fully support automation going forward with Windows 10.

```
Dim Req As Object, xmlobj As Object
Dim strWeb As String, myFile As String

' READ HTML PAGE
Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Req.Open "GET", "http://www.example.coms/", False
Req.send

' HTML/TEXT
strWeb = Req.responseText
myFile = "C:\Path\To\File.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Write #1, strWeb
Close #1

' XML
Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
myFile = "C:\Path\To\File.xml"
xmlObj.LoadXML Req.responseText
xmlObj.Save myFile

Set Req = Nothing
Set xmlObj = Nothing
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I'll have a go and post later on outcome. The main reason I use the IE object is to avoid having to write code to login to the sites as I can just be logged in on the browser.  Looking like this kind of lazy may not be an option in the future :(